# Is there an equivalent class for groovy's ConfigSlurper in java?

Tags: java, groovy, configuration

Below is a small example that I generally use in groovy, but I want something similar in java.

Configuration file

```
datastore{
    oracle{
        host="localhost"
        port=1521
        dbname="orcl"
    }
    db2{
        host="localhost"
        port=12807
        dbname="sppd"
    }
}
```

Groovy

```
public class Configuration {

    public static final def cfg = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File("configuration").toURL())

    static main(args) {
        println cfg.datastore.oracle.host
        println cfg.datastore.db2.host
    }

}
```

Comment: What part do you want "in Java"?

Comment: @Donal: To use nested configurations in java similar to [ConfigSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/ConfigSlurper) class

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you're wanting to access a property by its full path, e.g. `datastore.oracle.host` from Java like you can in Groovy. If so, do this:

```
ConfigObject config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File("configuration").toURL());
Map flattenedConfig = config.flatten();
String oracleHost = (String) flattenedConfig.get("datastore.oracle.host");
```

Better than Java properties because the type is maintained. From a [Groovy User list post](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Using-ConfigSlurper-from-Java-to-get-nested-props-td4866660.html).

Comment: Yes, I need something like your solution, currently I am not available to test this.. will check back once I am back. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That is too much dynamic groovyness, but can be expressed in XML, properties, etc. You can try [`Common Configuration`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_configurationbuilder.html), which would express the same data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<gui-definition>
  <colors>
    <background>#808080</background>
    <text>#000000</text>
    <header>#008000</header>
    <link normal="#000080" visited="#800080"/>
    <default>${colors.header}</default>
  </colors>
</gui-definition>
```

And read with:

```
XMLConfiguration config = new XMLConfiguration("tables.xml");
String backColor = config.getString("colors.background");
String textColor = config.getString("colors.text");
String linkNormal = config.getString("colors.link[@normal]");
```

You can also give a try to [`PropertyConfiguration`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html#Properties_files):

```
# Properties definining the GUI
colors.background = #FFFFFF
colors.foreground = #000080

window.width = 500
window.height = 300
```

Loaded with:

```
Configuration config = new PropertiesConfiguration("usergui.properties");
String backColor = config.getString("colors.background");
```